Дубликаты в модели Prisma
Пытаюсь создать две таблицы(модели): Пользователи и рефералки в prisma.
Код их должен выглядеть следующим образом:
model UsersTable {
  id         BigInt      @id
  username   String?
  /*тут ещё строки*/

  referred_users UsersTable[] @relation("UserReferrals_referrer")
  referrals      Referrals[]  @relation("UserReferrals_referrer")

  /*тут ещё строки*/
}

model Referrals {
  id               Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  referrer         UsersTable @relation("UserReferrals_referrer", fields: [referrer_id], references: [id])
  referred_user    UsersTable @relation("UserReferrals_referred_user", fields: [referred_user_id], references: [id])
  referrer_id      BigInt
  referred_user_id BigInt
}


Но при сохранении файла, prisma форматирует код и добавляет следующие поля в модели:
model UsersTable {
  /*прошлый код*/
  Referrals        Referrals[] // Что она добавляет
  Referrals        Referrals[] // И эту тоже, как дубль
}

model Referrals {
  /*прошлый код*/
  UsersTable       UsersTable? @relation(fields: [usersTableId], references: [id]) // Добавила
  usersTableId     BigInt? // Добавила
}


Кто-нибудь знает, почему так происходит и можно ли как-то это исправить?
Prisma-Version: 5.22.0
